# cross account s3 access using KMS key for IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

I am trying to set up cross-account s3 access using KMS key for IAM role. We are having 2 aws accounts. Let's call it account A and account B. Objective is to transfer file using lambda service in account A to the KMS key(customer managed) encrypted S3 bucket of account B. So In account B, I have updated KMS key policy like below.

Account A --> 12345678912

Account B --> 98765432198

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "key-default-1",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::98765432198:root"
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow administration of the key",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::98765432198:role/adminaccesstononprod"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Create*",
            "kms:Describe*",
            "kms:Enable*",
            "kms:List*",
            "kms:Put*",
            "kms:Update*",
            "kms:Revoke*",
            "kms:Disable*",
            "kms:Get*",
            "kms:Delete*",
            "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
            "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::98765432198:role/demo-sharedstorage-InternalRole"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::98765432198:role/demo-sharedstorage-ExternalRole"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow IAM role use of the key",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::98765432198:role/adminaccesstononprod"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow attachment using IAM role of persistent resources",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::98765432198:role/adminaccesstononprod"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:CreateGrant",
            "kms:ListGrants",
            "kms:RevokeGrant"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
                "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow attachment using internal IAM role of persistent resources",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::98765432198:role/demo-sharedstorage-InternalRole"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:CreateGrant",
            "kms:ListGrants",
            "kms:RevokeGrant"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
                "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow attachment using external IAM role of persistent resources",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::98765432198:role/demo-instance-profile-InstanceIAMRole"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:CreateGrant",
            "kms:ListGrants",
            "kms:RevokeGrant"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
                "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow instances to encrypt/decrypt with this key",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::98765432198:role/demo-instance-profile-InstanceIAMRole"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Actually let users use this key",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:username": "sit-actimize-*User-*"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow IAM role use of the key",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345678912:root"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow attachment using IAM role of persistent resources",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345678912:root"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:CreateGrant",
            "kms:ListGrants",
            "kms:RevokeGrant"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
                "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Which works as expected however when I change the ARN of account A from `arn:aws:iam::12345678912:root` to `arn:aws:iam::12345678912:role/file-transfer-lambda` for giving access to the specific role the lambda in Account A starts getting access denied error.

My understanding is that IAM role will have a privilege of using the KMS key and write to s3 bucket. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. I am refering following aws [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/share-custom-encryption-keys-more-securely-between-accounts-by-using-aws-key-management-service/)

Comment: Does the lambda itself has permissions to use KMS?

Comment: Yes. ARN of KMS key is shared with Account A and there is policy in Account A which allows lambda the use of KMS key.

Comment: When you are getting ` denied error` doesn't it specify which operation exactly is denied?

Comment: The lambda which does file transfer operation gives error as `Access Denied:  Access denied` however it doesn't specify for which operation.

Comment: If lambda has permissions for KMS, what about `Put*` permissions for the bucket?

Comment: Yes. `s3:Put*` and `s3:Get*` permissions are also present for s3 bucket.

Comment: I see. No more ideas for now. Maybe someone else will be able to help more.

Comment: This is resolved now. IAM role ARN which is being used in KMS key policy was wrong and after putting correct IAM role ARN it started working as expected.